# How to get current time from device in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

**How can I get the current time from device? I need possibly ways in kotlin language.**

Comment: try with above linked answer and paste in Kotlin file, android studio will itself convert the code in Kotlin for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here simple way to get the time!

```
val c = Calendar.getInstance()

val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

val hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
val minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 4):

try this...

```
LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

ex) 2021-12-02 17:17:03

---

LocalDateTime.now() require API level 26.
so, if API level 26 below,
you add `@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.0)` this code above your method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use old Calendar apis, it's [outdated and troublesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

Use `LocalDateTime` to get the system date and time

```
private fun getCurrentDate() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val dateTime = LocalDateTime.now()      // date time object
        val month = dateTime.month              // result DECEMBER
        val date = dateTime.dayOfMonth          // result 2 (current date )
        val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
        Log.d(
            "Date:", parssed date ${dateTime.format(formatter)}"
        )
    }
}
```

Change `FormatStyle` to `MEDIUM`,`SHORT`,`LONG`,`FULL` to change date format accordingly or you can use custom date parser format.

**Output**: Dec 2, 2021

**Note**: `DateTimeFormatter` only works in android 8 and above, to use it below android 8 [enable desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring)